# Center images in a row without using actual rows/lists

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I actually have two questions but I think they kind of go with each other and i'm not sure if that's against the rules so just let me know and I can split it into two different posts if need be.

Anyways onto the question(s), my first one is that i'm trying to figure out how to center my pictures. As you'll see in the code below, I didn't actually use the row or list element because wanted more flexibility for mobile usage. I want the images to be centered in a row, horizontally, on the page. I've tried a bunch of different things, namely a flexbox, but nothing thing is working.

My second question is about my header/navigation, I want it to span the whole page horizontally but there's a strange white border around it. I assume there's some sort of padding problem but
i've tried everything I can think of.

here's the html (I obviously have many more entries on the actual page)

```
<div class="content">
<div class="wrapper">

<!--- ENTRY --->

<div class="entry">
<div class="clip">
<div class="clothes"><img src="img/t1.jpg" alt="Mustard Long Sleeve Shirt"></div></div>
<div class="infohover">
<div class="info">
<li style="text-align:center;">
<b><div class="label">Long Sleeves</div></b><br>
<b>20.99</b><br>
<b>5 Colors</b><br>
<div class="stars"><img src="img/stars.png"></div>
<a>Quick View</a> </li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--- END ENTRY --->
<!--- ENTRY --->
<div class="entry">
<div class="clip">
<div class="clothes"><img src="img/t2.jpg" alt="White Blouse"></div></div>
<div class="infohover">
<div class="info">
<li style="text-align:center;">
<b><div class="label">Cotton Blouse</div></b><br>
<b>18.99</b><br>
<b>2 Colors</b><br>
<div class="stars"><img src="img/stars.png"></div>
<a>Quick View</a> </li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--- END ENTRY --->
</div>
</div>
```

Html for the header

```
<header>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Major+Mono+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <h1>District Apparel</h1>
</header>
```

Html for the navigation

```
<nav>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Major+Mono+Display|Oswald|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Shop Tops</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop Bottoms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop Dresses</a></li>
        <?php
            if ($mobile==false){
        ?>
        <li><a href="#">Shop Jackets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop Accessories</a></li>


        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's the CSS

```
h1 {
  background-color: #EDC7B7;
  Margin: 0;
  Padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Major Mono Display', monospace;
  color: #A41938;
  font-size: 40px;
  }

body {
    color: #828282;
    font-weight: 100;
    background:#f6f6f6;
    font-family:'champagne';
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;


}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    min-height: 800px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 100%;

}

.entry {
  background:#fff;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  width:310px;
  height:400px;
  border: solid #123C69 2px;
}

.clothes {
  z-index:9;
  margin-top:0px;
 }

.clothes img {
  width:310px;
  height:400px; }

.clip {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background:#fff;
  width:300px;
  height:350px; }
```

Edit: 
Here's the link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/khaleesijamie/pen/rNNxRmY) for a fuller picture of the project.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you're describing with the code provided. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A working codepen or similar would be very helpful, since pasting what you have provided does yield anything very sensible. As a comment though, don't have floated elements inside flex items. You seem to be guessing and trying things at random rather than taking the time to understand the underlying layout principles. If your container is flex, then the first level children will be centered if you use justify-content-center. But don't confuse things by also using float. Additionally, I'd comment that using list items does not reduce "flexibility" - a <li> can node can be styled like any other.

Comment: Sorry about that, i've edited the post and attached a link to a newly made codepen. I thought I had a decent handle on layout principles, but you may be right that I need to work on it a bit. What I mean is, flexibility in terms of the number of entries that will appear in a row depending on the size of the screen.

Comment: WRT flexibility, I understand, and a list can be styled appropriately for that. The list has a default styling of course, which you need to remove. But mainly it's semantic; it's saying that what follows is a list.

Comment: The markup in your first example is invalid HTML. Probably your last example, too. @seesharper If he posts his markup in a codepen, it will get this question closed quickly. Code is to be posted here, within the question, and **never** any third party site. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem with images can solve with flex properties

```css
    .wrapper {
       position: relative;
       top: 80px;
       margin-bottom: 100px;
       min-height: 800px;
       text-align: justify;
       line-height: 100%;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display: -webkit-box;
       display: flex;
       -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
       flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

Look at five last lines...

And your problem with white border around header, it is the margin of body. so:

```css
    body {
       color: #828282;
       font-weight: 100;
       background:#f6f6f6;
       font-family:'champagne';
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }
```

Look at two last lines...
And add this code begin of your style file to have no problem with padding in the future

```css
    * {
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

And sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `content` div altogether, and apply flex to the `wrapper` instead. All you need is `display: flex; justify-content: center: flex-wrap: wrap`. Note that the problem was happening because flex applies the the *direct children* of the flex box. You had the items two levels down.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making sure your HTML is valid. Attributes like `style="text-align:center;"` won't work if the elements they're being applied to aren't formed correctly.

Also your `<li>`'s are List Items and they need to be part of a list. Lists can be an ordered list `ol` (List Items will be numbered) or an unordered list `ul` (List Items will just be bullet points), the choice is yours, but either way List Items have to be included in a list first:

Use an unordered list

- when
- order
- doesn't
- matter

And an ordered list

1. when
2. it
3. does

And you have a couple `<div class="label">`'s in there, those should be your List Items (`li`'s). So instead of:

`<div class="label">Long Sleeves</div>`

I would change that to:

`<ul>
  <li>Long Sleeves</li>
</ul>`